# in Unity : Setting the orthographic camera to have a fixed pixel size

Tags: android, ios, camera, unity-game-engine

[image]

Look at the picture above.

You can see that the pixel size of the character is the same whether it is landscape mode or portrait mode.

What is the best practice for implementing this in Unity?

ps. camera is orthographical mode.

supplement:

[image]

The above is a screenshot taken with the size of the orthographic camera set to '3'.

One has a resolution of 640 x 360 and the other has a resolution of 360 x 640.

As you can see, the actual visible pixel size of the capsule in the center is quite different in both screenshot.

I've tried it on my device, too.

Comment: Have you tried doing this? Are you claiming the size of the character changes when you rotate?

Comment: this works out of the box

Comment: @Marc yes i claiming that.

Comment: I supplemented the text.

Comment: So from what I've seen in Unity, it cares about height first when it comes to the camera. If you change the width, it doesn't change the height. It's noticeable if you go from a 4:3 aspect to a 16:9 aspect. The height will always be the same but you'll be able to see more on the sides. I'm not sure if you can change this behavior but I'll look into it later. Your capsule isn't changing size in any way, it's only getting more screen real estate. You can see orientation in code, and I would use that to change the size of the screen programmatically if it changes from landscape to portrait.